# How to add reference from WebAPI to DataModel in ASP.NET WebAPI Solution

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have created one solution and inside that i have created 2 projects, one for the web api and the other for the data model. How can i use the data model in the web api project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: 1. Right click the project you want to use the data type in]

[image: 2. Tick all the projects you want the selected project to have access too]

[image: 3. Add a using statement at the top of every class file that you want to use the data model in]

1. Right click the project you want to use the data type in
2. Tick all the projects you want the selected project to have access too
3. Add a using statement at the top of every class file that you want to use the data model in

Answer (score 1):

Why 2 solutions. You can actually have one solution file with 2 projects in it. 
Once you build the solution you can see a dll in your data model project. You have to add reference of that dll in your project web api by right clicking on the reference and add reference where your data model project will be there. Click and add. You are done. Access data model in webapi by using right namespace.

Comment: I did that. Inside the DataModel project, i have created a repository which needs the web api project's app_start access. How can i do that?

Comment: Why some other project will need to have access to the app_start. Can you detail what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: yes, i have created a mongodb connection. So i have created a web api project in asp.net. The connection string is defined in the webapi app_start folder as mongodbcontext.cs.. the project should be expandable. So i was asked to create a seperate project for the data model. And in that model project i created a data handler which i have written the relevant methods to handle the web api post, get requests. i need access to the mongo db context file in the handler. How can i do that

Comment: Ohk. So my first comment should answer this. Just make sure you have public access modifier so that it’s visible on your webapi project.